# filter array of objects not returning filtered values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array of objects.

```
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "", short_name: "", short_name2: "", trickysort: "", …}
1: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Diamorphine", short_name: "07", short_name2: "", trickysort: "Diamorphine", …}
2: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Fentanyl", short_name: "06", short_name2: "P", trickysort: "Fentanyl", …}
3: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Fentanyl  2 mcg/ml", short_name: "02", short_name2: "E", trickysort: "Fentanyl  2 mcg/ml", …}
4: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Fentanyl 4 mcg/ml", short_name: "03", short_name2: "E", trickysort: "Fentanyl 4 mcg/ml", …}
5: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Morphine", short_name: "04", short_name2: "P", trickysort: "Morphine", …}
6: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "No Opioid", short_name: "01", short_name2: "", trickysort: "No Opioid", …}
7: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Other", short_name: "08", short_name2: "", trickysort: "Other", …}
8: {tbi_tblid: 512100013, long_name: "Oxycodone", short_name: "05", short_name2: "", trickysort: "Oxycodone", …}
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to filter the array to only contain objects that has a `short_name2` of the given/passed `code`

```
_correctOpioidOptions(type){
    if(type === 'epidural'){
        return {choiceOfOpioidsList_epi:this._filterList('e')}
    }else if(type === 'pca'){
        return {choiceOfOpioidsList_pca:this._filterList('p')}
    }
},
_filterList(code){
    let originalList = this.props.choiceOfOpioidsList;

    let newList = originalList.filter(function (item,code) {
        return item.short_name2.toLowerCase() === code;
    });

    console.log(newList);
},
```

But I end up with an empty array everytime. What am I missing?

I tried the following aswell.

```
_filterList(code){
    let originalList = this.props.choiceOfOpioidsList;

    let newList = originalList.filter(function (item,code) {
        if(return item.short_name2.toLowerCase() === code){
           return item;
        }
        return false;
    });

    console.log(newList);
},
```

Comment: It's not clear how you're actually calling `_filterList`, but the second argument of the callback passed to the `filter` method refers to the index of the array element being tested - see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax. This means that the `code` parameter you're passing to `_filterList` is being ignored (the `code` in the `return` statement of the callback does not refer to this parameter). This could be why it isn't working - and if it is, the fix is probably to just alter the function signature to `function (item)`.

Comment: basing this on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: There are three params passed in to the Array.filter callback by the filter internal code, they are element, index, and array.  `code`, being the second parameter, receives the index value of the array item being processed, which is not what you were expecting.

Comment: Is `_filterlist(code){ ..stuff },` react shortform for `_filterlist: function (code) { ..stuff }, ` or is that part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out only `short_name2` is equal to your passed `code` e.g **e**. Also add a check for `short_name2` variable like this way `short_name2!=""` to **non-empty** checking.

```js
const arr_obj = [{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"","short_name":"","short_name2":"","trickysort":""},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Diamorphine","short_name":"07","short_name2":"","trickysort":"Diamorphine"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Fentanyl","short_name":"06","short_name2":"P","trickysort":"Fentanyl"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Fentanyl  2 mcg/ml","short_name":"02","short_name2":"E","trickysort":"Fentanyl  2 mcg/ml"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Fentanyl 4 mcg/ml","short_name":"03","short_name2":"E","trickysort":"Fentanyl 4 mcg/ml"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Morphine","short_name":"04","short_name2":"P","trickysort":"Morphine"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"No Opioid","short_name":"01","short_name2":"","trickysort":"No Opioid"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Other","short_name":"08","short_name2":"","trickysort":"Other"},{"tbi_tblid":512100013,"long_name":"Oxycodone","short_name":"05","short_name2":"","trickysort":"Oxycodone"}]
let code = 'e';
result = arr_obj.filter((el,i)=>el.short_name2!="" && el.short_name2.toLowerCase()===code)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @morne glad it helps you some how. Best of luck :) Sir. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried renaming the code variable inside the filter function as index?

If it's due to scope, it'll take the closest scope variable name into game, comparing item with code, which is the index of the item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @yonexbat you should just be able to remove the erroneous parameter from your .filter callback:

```
_filterList(code){
    let originalList = this.props.choiceOfOpioidsList;

    let newList = originalList.filter(function (item) {
        return item.short_name2.toLowerCase() === code;
    });

    console.log(newList);
}
```